# Do we really need sufficiency for the Rao-Blackwell theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The [Rao-Blackwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem) states that conditioning an unbiased estimator of some parameter $\theta$ on a sufficient statistic can only reduce the variance of the estimator. However, couldn't we say that more generally, conditioning an unbiased estimator on *any random variable*, in fact on any sigma algebra at all, can only reduce the variance?

Let $\Sigma$ be some sigma algebra, $T$ an unbiased estimator for $\theta$, and $T'=E(T|\Sigma)$:

$$
\begin{align}
E((T'-\theta)^2) &= E((E(T|\Sigma) - \theta)^2) \\
                 &= E(E(T-\theta | \Sigma)^2)  \\
                 &\leq E(E((T-\theta)^2 | \Sigma)) \quad\text{(convexity)}\\
                 &=E((T-\theta)^2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: but will it remain a statistic?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Won't it? Obviously I'm taking $\Sigma$ to be a sub-sigma algebra of the ambient sigma algebra.

Comment: I don't think so. Generally the conditional expectation of a statistic will depend on the parameter unless you're conditioning with respect to a sufficient statistic. (This is just the definition of sufficiency when you think about it).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, I see the problem - if $\Sigma$ is the trivial tribe, for example, the estimator for $\theta$ you end up with is just $\theta$ itself, not very useful. In fact $T'$ is indeed "a statistic" in some sense - it's definitely $\sigma(X)$ measurable, where $X$ is the observation - but the real problem is that $T'$ doesn't even refer to a single random variable, you would get a different random variable for each value of $\theta$.

Comment: Yep. Statistic means it's only a function of the data and not the parameter. The conditional expectation is useless as an estimator if it depends on the parameter. (Alternatively if we're being Bayesian and our space includes the parameter as a RV, it won't be $X$-measurable.)

Comment: Okay. If you feel like summarizing that as an answer I'll accept it. By the way, does my calculation still show that for fixed $\theta$, conditioning an unbiased statistic reduces its variance?

Comment: Yep, I see no problem with your argument. Conditioning should always reduce variance (you have more info). Although again gotta be careful that you don't imply the result of doing so is a statistic.